# Does appending z to BST make it UTC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timezone, utc

The date is entered from UI in BST time zone (say 03/02/2016 00:00) . Saved in DB as same (03/02/2016 00:00) BST . In a response generated , the date is sent as 2016-02-03T00:00:00Z (which format??) . Since there is Z appended, does it mean we are converting from BST to UTC? Pls explain.

Comment: UTC has no daylight saving settings, while BST has. So you cannot mix them in the way above. An official conversion from BST to UTC is required.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- `BST` [can refer to](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) any of "British Summer Time" (UTC+1), "Bangladesh Standard Time" (UTC+6) or "Bougainville Standard Time" (UTC+11).  For the rest of this answer, I'll assume you meant the first one.
- In 2016, the UK switched from GMT (UTC+0) to BST (UTC+1) [on March 27th](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london?year=2016).  Thus on the date you provided (February 3rd), *BST was not in effect*.
- There's no way to tell if a conversion is being attempted given the values you provided, because the local time on that date happens to be zero hours offset from UTC.  If you test with a date in the middle of the summer, and find that the resulting value is one hour less than the input, then indeed a conversion to UTC is occuring.
- The `Z` is the UTC designator in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) formats.  Appending it indicates that the value given is meant to be interpreted in terms of UTC.  If your values are indeed in UTC, then the `Z` is correctly there.  If actually your values are meant to be interpreted as being in the local time in London, then you should append the offset instead (even if it's zero).  For example:

  - `2016-02-03T00:00:00+00:00` (GMT)
  - `2016-04-01T00:00:00+01:00` (BST)